# Importing libraries from CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I am very, very new to CMake, and I have configured and built a CMake project, but how do I actually import this CMake cache into a visual studio community 2022 project? I apologize for my inexperience, but there is a limited amount of documentation on this subject and most of the information available is made for Linux.

Comment: How did you build your project exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmake can generate projects and solution for Visual Studio.

Just start:

```
cmake -S PATH_TO_SOURCE_DIR -B PATH_TO_OUTPUT_DIR
```

PATH_TO_SOURCE_DIR - dir with CMakeLists.txt
PATH_TO_OUTPUT_DIR - dir for build results

After cmake finishes it's work you can find the *.vcxproj and *.sln files in the PATH_TO_OUTPUT_DIR.

Than just open sln file in Visual Studio.